# Data not fetched according to datepicker

Tags: android

I have a datepicker and spinner.I fetch data according to startdate and enddate.The data fetched between entered date range will listed into listView.But currently the data is not fetched according to the date range.It always show data between 1-nov-2017 to march 10-2018 .Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
**My activity**

     public class previous extends AppCompatActivity {
    static TextView startDate,endDate;
    static int DATES=123;



    CustomAdapter adapter, Padapter, Eadapter;
    ArrayList<AsyncTask> asyncTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView customersList;
    Spinner listOptions;
    final static String ALL = "All", PAYMENTS = "Payments", EXPENSES = "Expenses";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers);
        startDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.start_date);
        endDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.end_date);
        customersList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customers_list);
//        getCustomers(DATES);

        //Spinner
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        options.add(ALL);
        options.add(PAYMENTS);
        options.add(EXPENSES);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_spinner_white, options);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
        listOptions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        listOptions.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listOptions.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (listOptions.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                    case ALL:
                        searchView.setQuery("", true);
                        customersList.setAdapter(adapter);

                        break;
                    case PAYMENTS:
                        searchView.setQuery("", true);
                        customersList.setAdapter(Padapter);
                        break;
                    case EXPENSES:
                        searchView.setQuery("", true);
                        customersList.setAdapter(Eadapter);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        listOptions.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    public void getDates(View view){
        final TextView requiredDate=(TextView)view;
        final String oldText=requiredDate.getText().toString();
        final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Calendar selectedDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                //Setting display text-------
                SimpleDateFormat formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
                requiredDate.setText(formatted.format(selectedDate.getTime()));
                //Validation--------------
                if(!startDate.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.start_date))
                        &&!endDate.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.end_date))){
                    try {
                        Date sDate=formatted.parse(startDate.getText().toString());
                        Date eDate=formatted.parse(endDate.getText().toString());
                        if(sDate.after(eDate)){
                            Common.toastMessage(previous.this,R.string.give_valid);
                            requiredDate.setText(oldText);
                            return;
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        requiredDate.setText(oldText);
                        return;
                    }
                    getCustomers(DATES);
                }
            }
        };
        new DatePickerDialog(previous.this, dateSetListener, today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .show();
    }

    void getCustomers(int DATES) {

        final Common common = new Common();
        final String webService = "/API/Approver/GetPreviousApprovalsInfo";
        final String postData = "{\"FromDate\":\"" + startDate.getText().toString() + "\",\"ToDate\":\"" + endDate.getText().toString() + "\"}";
        final AVLoadingIndicatorView loadingIndicator = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        final String[] dataColumns = {};
        final Runnable postThread = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    final JSONArray invoices = new JSONArray(common.json);
                    if (invoices.length() == 0) {
                        (findViewById(R.id.no_items)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return;
                    }
                    final ArrayList<String[]> invoiceListData = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < invoices.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = invoices.getJSONObject(i);
                        String[] data = new String[9];
                        data[0] = jsonObject1.getString("ID");
                        data[1] = jsonObject1.getString("EntryNo");
                        data[2] = jsonObject1.getString("Company");
                        data[3] = jsonObject1.getString("Date");
                        data[4] = jsonObject1.getString("PaymentMode");
                        data[5] = jsonObject1.getString("Amount");
                        data[6] = jsonObject1.getString("Type");
                        data[7] = jsonObject1.getString("ApprovalDate");
                        data[8] = jsonObject1.getString("GeneralNotes");
                        invoiceListData.add(data);
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(previous.this, invoiceListData, Common.PREVIOUSPAYMENTS);
                    customersList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    final ArrayList<String[]> PaymentListData = new ArrayList<>();
                    final ArrayList<String[]> ExpenseListData = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < invoiceListData.size(); i++) {
                        if (invoiceListData.get(i)[6].equals("Payment")) {

                            PaymentListData.add(invoiceListData.get(i));


                        } else if (invoiceListData.get(i)[6].equals("Expense")) {

                            ExpenseListData.add(invoiceListData.get(i));


                        }
                    }

                    Padapter = new CustomAdapter(previous.this, PaymentListData, Common.PREVIOUSPAYMENTS);//Global variable
                    customersList.setAdapter(Padapter);
                    listOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    Eadapter = new CustomAdapter(previous.this, ExpenseListData, Common.PREVIOUSPAYMENTS);
                    customersList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    customersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                            if (customersList.getAdapter() == adapter) {


                                switch (invoiceListData.get(position)[6]){

                                    case "Payment":
                                        Intent approvalDetailsIntent1 = new Intent(previous.this,PpaymentDetails.class);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.APPROVALID,invoiceListData.get(position)[0]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.ENTRYNO, invoiceListData.get(position)[1]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.PAYMENT_MODE, invoiceListData.get(position)[4]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.PAYMENT_DATE, invoiceListData.get(position)[3]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.AMOUNT, invoiceListData.get(position)[5]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.COMPANY_DETAILS, invoiceListData.get(position)[2]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.GENERAL_NOTES, invoiceListData.get(position)[8]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.PAYMENT_TYPE, invoiceListData.get(position)[6]);
                                        startActivity(approvalDetailsIntent1);


                                        break;

                                    case "Expense":

                                        Intent approvalDetailsIntent2 = new Intent(previous.this, PexpenseDetail.class);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent2.putExtra(Common.APPROVALID, invoiceListData.get(position)[0]);
                                        approvalDetailsIntent2.putExtra(Common.REFNO, invoiceListData.get(position)[1]);
                                        startActivity(approvalDetailsIntent2);


                                        break;


                                }

//                                    Common.toastMessage(getContext(), "scene aan");
                            }

                            else if (customersList.getAdapter() == Padapter) {

                                Intent approvalDetailsIntent1 = new Intent(previous.this,PpaymentDetails.class);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.APPROVALID, PaymentListData.get(position)[0]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.ENTRYNO, PaymentListData.get(position)[1]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.PAYMENT_MODE, PaymentListData.get(position)[4]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.PAYMENT_DATE, PaymentListData.get(position)[3]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.AMOUNT, PaymentListData.get(position)[5]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.COMPANY_DETAILS, PaymentListData.get(position)[2]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.GENERAL_NOTES, PaymentListData.get(position)[8]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent1.putExtra(Common.PAYMENT_TYPE, PaymentListData.get(position)[6]);
                                startActivity(approvalDetailsIntent1);


                            }
                            else if (customersList.getAdapter() == Eadapter) {


                                Intent approvalDetailsIntent2 = new Intent(previous.this, PexpenseDetail.class);
                                approvalDetailsIntent2.putExtra(Common.APPROVALID, ExpenseListData.get(position)[0]);
                                approvalDetailsIntent2.putExtra(Common.REFNO, ExpenseListData.get(position)[1]);
                                startActivity(approvalDetailsIntent2);
                            }


                        }
                    });




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        Runnable postThreadFailed = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Common.toastMessage(previous.this, R.string.failed_server);
            }
        };

        common.AsynchronousThread(previous.this,
                webService,
                postData,
                loadingIndicator,
                dataColumns,
                postThread,
                postThreadFailed);
        asyncTasks.add(common.asyncTask);
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    }
    SearchView searchView;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_search, menu);
        //Searching-------------------
        searchView=(SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if(customersList.getAdapter()!=null){//for searching
                    ((CustomAdapter)customersList.getAdapter()).getFilter(Arrays.asList(1)).filter(searchView.getQuery().toString().trim());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_home) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,HomeScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        for(int i=0;i<asyncTasks.size();i++){
            asyncTasks.get(i).cancel(true);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tech.thrithvam.spaccounts.Customers"
    android:background="@drawable/primary_gradient">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:id="@+id/dates_layout"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_date"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:onClick="getDates"
            android:id="@+id/start_date"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/to"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_date"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:onClick="getDates"
            android:id="@+id/end_date"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/customers_list"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:indicatorName="BallScaleMultipleIndicator"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:indicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First please only ask one question in one question. Second questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Ben bro help me

Comment: The Question is not clear. Could you please specific which part of your code is not working

Comment: @VinayakB bro public void getdates() is working.But i think it not passing value to void getCustomers().I dont know how to.

Comment: Please Log postData and let me know it contains correct FromDate and toDate